# bootstrap-select, center title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select and trying to center select list title, but not managed to do this so far.
I've tried center title using title :

```
<select class="selectpicker" style="text-align: center;" title="Select one">
```

and data-title:

```
<select class="selectpicker" style="text-align: center;" data-title="Select one">
```

and using data-hidden option:

```
<option data-hidden="true" class="text-center" value="">Select one</option>
```

However, title is always aligned on left. Any tips what might work?

Answer (score 3):

maybe

```
text-align-last: center;
```

would help

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
select {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```